# How can I leave r.recognize_google to keep listening and dont stop

Tags: python, nlp, speech-recognition, chatbot

Im working in a chatbot and it works fine so far, however, if you dont talk directly after the chatbot talks to you, it gives you this error.

**in recognize_google
if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.UnknownValueError**

I want to be able for the chatbot to leave it on the background listening and not stoping for this errors.

This is the code that listens

```
    while True:

       with mic as source:
           audio = r.listen(source)
           sentence = r.recognize_google(audio, language="es-ES")
       print(f"You: {sentence}")


       if sentence == "cierra":
           break
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to respond so late, but you need to write something like this:
(just make an exception for the sr.UnknownValueError so when you are silent the program ignores it)

```
while True:

   with mic as source:
       try:
           audio = r.listen(source)
          sentence = r.recognize_google(audio, language="es-ES")
          print(f"You: {sentence}")

       except sr.UnknownValueError:
           pass 

   if sentence == "cierra":
       break
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding an explanation of the code you supplied.